# sum within groups when NA

Tags: r

I have data frame with 3 columns (ID, date, days). Column X is what i would like to get. When there is NA I would like to sum days from previous month with number of days of current month. Is it possible to do it with dplyr? I tried to do it with for loop but it takes too much time as i have more than 5M rows

```
  ID     date        days    X
  A     2014-01-31     NA   NA
  A     2014-02-28     NA   NA
  A     2014-03-31      4    4
  A     2014-04-30     NA   34
  A     2014-05-31     NA   65
  A     2014-06-30     NA   95
  A     2014-07-31     NA  126  
  B     2014-01-31     NA   NA
  B     2014-02-28     11   11
  B     2014-03-31      6    6
  B     2014-04-30     NA   36
  B     2014-05-31      6    6
  B     2014-06-30     NA   36
  C     2015-01-31     NA   NA
  C     2015-02-28     NA   NA
```

Comment: Sorry... is not clear exactly what you want to achieve. What, for example, do you want to achieve when there is no NA in your X column?

Comment: column 'X' isn't given. It is the result I would like to get based on calculations performed on column 'days'

Comment: Could you show your code as it is not clear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt using `tidyverse`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(new = cumsum(!is.na(days))+1) %>% 
 group_by(ID, new) %>% 
 mutate(new1 = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(days), as.numeric(diff.difftime(date)), days)), 
        new1 = replace(new1, new == 1, NA)) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-new)

# A tibble: 15 x 5
#       ID       date  days     X  new1
#   <fctr>     <date> <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1      A 2014-01-31    NA    NA    NA
# 2      A 2014-02-28    NA    NA    NA
# 3      A 2014-03-31     4     4     4
# 4      A 2014-04-30    NA    34    35
# 5      A 2014-05-31    NA    65    65
# 6      A 2014-06-30    NA    95    96
# 7      A 2014-07-31    NA   126   126
# 8      B 2014-01-31    NA    NA    NA
# 9      B 2014-02-28    11    11    11
#10      B 2014-03-31     6     6     6
#11      B 2014-04-30    NA    36    36
#12      B 2014-05-31     6     6     6
#13      B 2014-06-30    NA    36    36
#14      C 2015-01-31    NA    NA    NA
#15      C 2015-02-28    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. There is one problem when there is NA at  the end of one ID and at the beginning of another. Results are then wrong

Comment: @Koles, edit that into your question. Include any corner cases that might be there so we don't overfit our answers

Comment: I edited my qustion. I included two NA's and a case without any problems with machines. I think that's all

Comment: Ah ok I see it now. I will give it a look as soon as I come back from lunch. No food, no play :)